# Cannot Debug using Visual Studios on a Silverlight project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

When I try to run a Silverlight project in Visual Studios 2008 I get this error all of a sudden:

**Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight managed debugging package isn’t installed.**

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was I had installed SilverLight 4 when banging around on the web and needed to install it again using the developer verison [Silverlight_Developer.exe](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039).  I suppose this is kind of a well, duh, but maybe it will save someone else the pain.

Comment: This was a well, duh moment for me too.  Thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try below steps:

1. Right click your Web project
2. Select Web
3. Find Debuggers
4. Check Silverlight

That's it!